# Error Domain=IDETestOperationsObserverErrorDomain Code=12 "Failed to background test runner"

Tags: ios, jenkins, xcodebuild, xcode-ui-testing

I am running `xcodebuild test` for testing ui test. Running from Jenkins job.

Facing same issue again and again the below issue,

> xcodebuild[8028:16918138] Error
>   Domain=IDETestOperationsObserverErrorDomain Code=12 "Failed to
>   background test runner.
>
> Testing failed:   Test target MyAppUITests encountered an error
>   (Failed to background test runner. If you believe this error
>   represents a bug, please attach the log file at
>   /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/***.log)
>
> ** TEST FAILED **

I found nothing in the log location.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Xcode 8.2.1, UI tests run from fastlane snapshot. Interestingly, the first test passes but the second fails. The only difference is the language passed to the app (cs-CZ vs en-US, respectively)

Comment: I faced a similar issue under Xcode8.3 and submitted a bug report to apple. Are you also using Xcode8.3?

Comment: @SvenDriemecker Would you mind sharing the radar number? Ideally on openradar.appspot.com so I can dupe it?